svnrdump: E175002: REPORT request on '/svn/repo' failed
I am trying to split up an old single, multi-project repository into multiple smaller repos, one repo per project. I do not have access to the physical machine on which either the backup or the split-up repos are stored, so I am trying to use the svnrdump command to back up the old repo and then use svnrdumpfilter to split it into separate project-specific dump files, each which will then be svnrdump load-ed to their new homes.  The problem is that, when I run svnrdump dump, there are exactly 11 revisions out of the > 40,000 revisions in the repository that halt the entire process with the following error:
svnrdump: E175002: REPORT request on '/svn/repo' failed

The only thing I have difinitively nailed down is that all 11 of those commits come from the same project, but they come from different branches within that project. I am not sure how to fix this issue, get around it so I can just get a working dump file and move on, or just how to proceed in general. Any advice would be helpful.
